# Propeller blades flat vs wing shape

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, fan

Does a propeller blade with the shape of a wing produce more lift than a flat blade and will a blade with a wing shape produce lift in a ducted fan situation?

Comment: A propeller blade IS a wing, mounted vertically. https://howthingsfly.si.edu/propulsion/propellers

Comment: So can you tell me what will be the best angle of Attack?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that when you say shape of a wing you mean an aerodynamic profile.

If that's the case, then yes, an aerodynamic profile is better at creating lift than a flat blade. How much depends on which profile is used and the conditions it is used in, as every profile is optimized for a different purpose.

As for your second question, a ducted fan **IS** a propeller, so it does produce lift, just as any other propeller would.