# Angle of attack of a propeller blade

Tags: aerodynamics, flow, fan

What will be the best angle of attack for a propeller blade that is in the airfoil shape?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445235/2451

Comment: try posting this on the aviation stack exchange. lots of propeller experts over there.

Answer (score 1):

A propeller blade is shaped in a spiral plane gradually twisting more as it gets closer to the shaft, to create a uniform flow so as to avoid slow flow near the shaft, so the angle of attack varies along the length of blade.

The best angle of attack depends on many things: speed of the airplane, load-demand on the propeller, air density, engine power, airplane's pitch and attitude.

Many of the advanced airplane propellers' angle of attack are adjustable by pilot.

Comment: You're right, except for the end of the first sentence. The angle of the propeller blade is more extreme near the shaft, not to vary the angle of attack, but to keep it the same.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, Angle of attack is defined as the angle of airfoil cord line with the flow of air. And because the incoming flow is uniform and aligned with the planes flight path, propellers angle of attack varies to compensate for variation of speed along its length.

Comment: The propeller's angle changes in order to keep the angle of attack as nearly constant as possible. Sounds like maybe I need to show a diagram. Here's a start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7hyrD9-R4A

Comment: @Mike Dunlaveu, I am a pilot, and consider myself educated enough to accept the huge responsibility entailed. There are many videos in many places, many comments even in this site, doesn't mean they are true. I recommend you Google NASA or Wikipedia for definition of angle of attack, propeller pitch, twisted airfoils. Wing twist. The idea for tapering off the end of propeller and giving it the least angle of attack is to make it stall last.

Comment: I'm a pilot too. Here's my idea. Suppose airspeed is $50$ m/s, and prop rotation rate is $200$ rad/s. Suppose AOA should be $10°$ at all prop radii. So at a radius of $1$m, the prop pitch should be $atan(50/200)+10 = 24°$. At a radius of $1/2$ meter, the pitch should be $atan(50/100)+10 = 37°$. So to keep the same AOA along the prop, its pitch has to increase at smaller radius, or decrease at larger radius. Did I make a mistake? (I'm sure you're right about the tip stalling last.)

Comment: @Mike Dunlaveu, you seem to have a confused notion about the angle of attack. AOT doesn't have anything to do with the speed, it is the angle between the cord of airfoil at the cross section under consideration and wind flow. Nothing to do with the speed. Please be careful if you're a pilot, you need to correct this idea.

Comment: AOA of the wing has nothing to do with airspeed. AOA of a propeller blade (which is a wing of course, but it travels at right angles to the airplane's motion) has everything to do with airspeed.